# Efficiently nth line of many files to another file

Tags: bash, text-processing

For a project I have to work with large data sets and have hit a problem (that I did not anticipate).

- I have a folder of ~10000 files (of 10000 "patients") each containing ~2 million entries (measurements).
- For further analysis I need to make a comparison of every measurement between these patients.

Thus, I want to make 2 million files, each with 10000 entries. However using Bash, this seemed not to be feasible by my approach which is basically:

```
awk 'FNR==$1' $INPUTPATH > $OUTPUTPATH
```

where I put in the row number for `$1` and parallelize it on ~1000 cores.

Is there any way to make this much more efficient?

Comment: Not doing anything in Bash would be an excellent first step. Using an interpreted language to process 20 billion lines is not good. Two ways: (a) Split each piece of data with a pair of keys, relating to Measurement and Patient. Sort that so the data comes out measurement first. Then stitch all the values for a measurement together (as you now get them in a group). But far better: put it all in a proper database, because you are going to need all kinds of other processing anyway that you have also not anticipated.

Comment: Also (as a side-note) your `awk` program wouldn't work: Inside single quotes, shell variable expansion is suppressed, so `$1` would be interpreted by `awk` as referring to the value in the first column of the current line, and not by the shell as the first command-line argument of your shell script. If you want to know how to use shell variables in `awk` , have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

Comment: OK, thanks for the answers

Comment: It would help to know how the filenames work (some pattern for the Patients files), and how you plan to generate 2 million unique filenames for the Measurements. Also, are you relying on one-on-one ordering for the corresponding measurements, or do they have ids such as names or numbers, and are they really one per line?

Comment: Adding to `2 million file names` for the outputs: many file systems search for file names linearly, which gets horribly slow. If I was naming two million files like `0745964`, they would go in directories like `0745/0745964` or `074/0745964` (leading zeros to preserve any ordering).

Comment: For some forms of "comparison", you can do the calculation cumulatively, and not need to invert the entire matrix. For example, to find min, max, mean and standard deviation of a specific measurement, you only need to store Min, Max, n, Sum(x), Sum(x * x). That's only 40 bytes per measurement, so an array for 2 million measurements is under 100 MB. You can do that by reading each file once serially.

Answer (score 0):

> awk 'FNR==$1' $INPUTPATH > $OUTPUTPATH

The problem here is that **awk** continues reading the file after a match.
If you use **sed** instead then you can easy stop reading the file.

Eg. if you (only) want line 1000 from a file called F1 using **sed**

```bsh
/usr/bin/sed -n -e '1000p' -e '1000q' F1
```

Here is a shell-scripts which I think solves your problem:

```bsh
for AFILE in "$INPUTPATH"
do
  POS=1
  while read -r ALINE
  do
    echo "$ALINE" >> "$OUTPUTPATH"/$POS
    POS=$((POS+1))
  done
done
```

Comment: The "stop reading" method in `sed` about halves the runtime on average. For every `-e 1000q` which reads 0.01% of the file, there is a corresponding `-e 1999000q` which reads 99.9% of the file. Nothing can hide the fact that this method reads half (on average) of each 2M-line file 10,000 times, and then opens, appends and closes output files 20 billion times.